# Why some of the string variable not taking inputs from structure to void function?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, structure

In the below code some of the string is taking inputs but some are just skipping. I checked everything didn't discover anything. It would be ideal if you let me know where I am fouling up.**I need to mention that I have a lot more work to do on this problem that's why I created functions**

**Expected Output**

::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Choose Option From Below
::::::::::::::::::::::::::

1.for add new student

2.for add new teacher

3.for add new notice

1

Enter student's first name : Marry

Enter student's last name :lisa

Enter student's roll no :245

Enter student's section : C

Enter student's year :1

Enter student's semester :2

Enter student's department : IR

Enter student's email :lisa2@hotmail.com

Enter student's phone :15648955

Enter student's address : 2/A XYZ street

**Output Now**

::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Choose Option From Below
::::::::::::::::::::::::::

1.for add new student

2.for add new teacher

3.for add new notice

1

Enter student's first name :Enter student's last name :lisa

Enter student's roll no :245

Enter student's section :Enter student's year :1

Enter student's semester :2

Enter student's department :Enter student's email :lisa2@hotmail.com

Enter student's phone :15648955

Enter student's address :

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 52.725 s
Press any key to continue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct student{
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int Roll;
    string Section;
    int Year;
    int Semester;
    string Department;
    string Email;
    int Phone;
    string Address;
};

void student_part(void){
    struct student stu;
    cout<<"Enter student's first name :";
    getline(cin,stu.firstName);
    cout<<"Enter student's last name :";
    getline(cin,stu.lastName);
    cout<<"Enter student's roll no :";
    cin>>stu.Roll;
    cout<<"Enter student's section :";
    getline(cin,stu.Section);
    cout<<"Enter student's year :";
    cin>>stu.Year;
    cout<<"Enter student's semester :";
    cin>>stu.Semester;
    cout<<"Enter student's department :";
    getline(cin,stu.Department);
    cout<<"Enter student's email :";
    getline(cin,stu.Email);
    cout<<"Enter student's phone :";
    cin>>stu.Phone;
    cout<<"Enter student's address :";
    getline(cin,stu.Address);
}



void add_info(void){
    int choice;
    cout<<"::::::::::::::::::::::::::"<<endl;
    cout<<" Choose Option From Below"<<endl;
    cout<<"::::::::::::::::::::::::::"<<endl;
    cout<<"\n1.for add new student"<<endl;
    cout<<"2.for add new teacher"<<endl;
    cout<<"3.for add new notice"<<endl;
    cin>>choice;
    if(choice==1){
        student_part();
    }
}


int main()
{
    add_info();
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code for better legibility.

Comment: @ThomasSablik no it doesn't match the thing I need

Comment: The solution described in the dupe is: call `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')` after all `cin>>...;`

Comment: and phone number wasn't part of the question either.

Comment: _"and phone number wasn't part of the question either"_ Then you shouldn't post it in your [mcve]

Comment: @ThomasSablik I read the link or not how do you know? I read the link twice. I couldn't understand and match the problem that's what I get. and about the phone number I posted because I wasn't able to find where I was doing mistakes I also mentioned that. I think this was not the part where was the mistake I can assume at least. Whatever thanks for your so useful informations and vote. Good Luck!

Comment: The title of the dupe is _"Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction? "_ and the question is why `std::getline` after `std::cin` doesn't work. In your code all `std::getline` after `std::cin` doesn't work. You had to read only the title and 10 lines of code to see that this is exactly your problem.

Comment: @ThomasSablik my problem wasn't about why ```std::getline``` after ```std::cin``` doesn't work. My problem was getline() wasn't working on some certain situations. if you can see my output.it works after ```cin``` sometimes and sometimes not so how do you want me to explain with the link's explanation where it didn't work anytime when ```cin``` and ```getline``` used?

Comment: That's the problem with this question and the accepted answer. You still don't understand the problem and probably will repeat it. Look again at your output. **All** `std::geline` directly after `std::cin` are skipped. That's because `std::cin` is a formatted read and doesn't remove the newline. `std::getline` is an unformatted read and reads the previous newline after a formatted read. `getline(cin,stu.firstName);` is skipped after `cin>>choice;`, `getline(cin,stu.Section);` is skipped after `cin>>stu.Roll;`, `getline(cin,stu.Department);` is skipped after `cin>>stu.Semester;`, ...

Comment: okay. I didn't understand the full concept from that link now how can I understand and what is the main solution?

Comment: The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21567292/4645334 is divided into multiple sections. There is a basic explanation for beginners, an in-depth explanation that you can skip and multiple solutions. You should read it until you understand it. If you don't understand something you should ask. I already gave you a short version in my comment: _"The solution described in the dupe is: call `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')` after all `cin>>...;`"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cin>>stu.Phone;
```

Is fetching an integer from the command line so it doesn’t read the `\n` character at the end which `getline` reads immediately after.

Before `getline`, write `fgetc(stdin)` to read the newlîne.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibillity would be to change all `getLine()` fucntions to `cin>>stu...` calls.

The error occurs, because the `cin` method doas not take the `\n` out of the input buffer. The following `getLine` takes the remaining `\n` out of the input Buffer and instantly terminates.